# how to format data of retrieve viewset on EVRY instance of object

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, postgresql, django-rest-framework

so here is my issue i dont know how to specify it cause it would too complicated but i have an easy question that will solve my issue anyway so here it is.

i want to retrieve datas from table (model) that has a field named "name" and i want at each row retrieved i want to format it's value (by adding removing etc.. characters) this value will then be returned to axios.get() request, and the most important thing is that i want to do it in the retrieve function of the viewset class otherwise it wont solve my problem
here is some exemples of the code

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name= models.TextField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'person'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Person.objects.all()
serializer_class = PersonSerializer

def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("inside retrieve")

    if request.query.consultation_person://execute this if the parameter consultation_person is true (i want to format the Person.name value only if this parameter is given by axios.get() )
        //i want to format each instance of the object Person.name returned befor it sends to axios.get()


        return super().retrieve(request)

    return super().retrieve(request)
```

thanks in advance for your answer :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/db/sql/) helped me solve the issue I just had to do my editing on each loop instance of the sql raw request fetching:

```
people = Person.objects.raw('SELECT *, age(birth_date) AS age FROM myapp_person')
```